# How to avoid unrecognised callback in Rails Class after calling skip_callback for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm getting a error in a RoR application where there's a new feature using skip_callback method.

```
class Foo
    before_save: :some_callback
    
    def some_callback
    end
end
```

When there's multiples call to the class, raise Argument error because of rails functionality created on this [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19029).

```
# I using this only with the purpose of showing the error, 
# I know that the block will execute without errors if calling set_callback after skip:
5.times do 
   Foo.skip_callback(:save, :before, :some_callback)
end
ArgumentError (Before save callback :some_callback has not been defined)
```

I know that I can avoid raise a error if I use the method like this

```
skip_callback(:save, :before, :some_callback, raise: false)
```

But I don't really feel 100% confident of this approach, there's a better way to skip calling the callbacks without raising a error if call the class multiple times? I'm afraid another part of the code, call the same class and don't call the callback when it's needed.

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by "I'm afraid another part of the code, call the same class and don't call the callback when it's needed". Do you want to disable this callback in one context, but have it executed in some another?

Comment: Yes, lets say I have a admin interface who crente new records and a web interface which call without the need of calling the callbacks.

Comment: When you have the situation where certain data entities behave differently depending on the context and/or operation, it's hight time to move away from ActiveRecord callbacks, validations and all these "simple solutions for simple problems". Don't fight with AR magic, instead, move all the record(s) creation logic into separate objects that will handle the complexity in a straightforward manner. (PS I know it doesn't answer your question, but I do think AR callbacks is not the way to go if you need to fight with them)